# What are the differences between Servlet 2.5 and 3?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm rolling J2EE code that adheres to Servlet 2.5 and I'm wondering what are the major differences between 2.5 and 3. Pointers to official Sun docs and personal experiences are most appreciated.

If I shouldn't be concerning myself with 3 for the time being, just say so. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Just waiting for answers :)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

UPDATE

Just as an update and to be more explicit, these are the main differences between servlets 2.5 and 3 (I'm not trying to be exhaustive, I'm just mentioning the most interesting parts):

### Annotations to declare servlets, filters and listeners (ease of development)

In servlets 2.5, to declare a servlet with one init parameter you need to add this to **web.xml**:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.server.side.stuff.MyAwesomeServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>configFile</param-name>
        <param-value>config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/to/my/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In servlets 3, **web.xml** is optional and you can use annotations instead of XML. The same example:

```
@WebServlet(name="myServlet",
    urlPatterns={"/path/to/my/servlet"},
    initParams={@InitParam(name="configFile", value="config.xml")})
public class MyAwesomeServlet extends HttpServlet { ... }
```

For filters, you need to add this in **web.xml** in servlets 2.5:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.server.side.stuff.MyAwesomeServlet</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/to/my/filter</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Equivalent using annotations in servlets 3:

```
@ServletFilter(name="myFilter", urlPatterns={"/path/to/my/filter"})
public class MyAwesomeFilter implements Filter { ... }
```

For a listener (in this case a ServletContextListener), in servlets 2.5:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>my.server.side.stuff.MyAwesomeListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The same using annotations:

```
@WebServletContextListener
public class MyAwesomeListener implements ServletContextListener { ... }
```

### Modularization of web.xml (Pluggability)

- In servlets 2.5 there is just one monolithic **web.xml** file.
- In servlets 3, each "loadable" jar can have a **web-fragment.xml** in its **META-INF** directory specifying servlets, filters, etc. This is to allow libraries and frameworks to specify their own servlets or other objects.

### Dynamic registration of servlets, filters and listeners at context initialization time (Pluggability)

In servlets 3, a `ServletContextListener` can add dynamically servlets, filters and listeners using the following methods added to `SevletContext`: `addServlet()`, `addFilter()` and `addListener()`

### Asynchronous support

Example: say that some servlet container has five threads in its thread pool, and there is a time-consuming process to be executed per request (like a complex SQL query).

- With servlets 2.5 this servlet container would run out of available threads if it receives five requests at the same time and the five available threads start doing the process, because the threads wouldn't return until `service()` (or `doGet()`, `doPost()`, etc.)  is executed from start to end and returns a response.
- With servlets 3.0, this long-time process can be delegated to another thread and finish `service()` before sending the response (the response now will be sent by the latest thread). This way the thread is free to receive new responses.

An example of asynchronous support:

Servlets 2.5:

```
public class MyAwesomeServlet extends HttpSerlvet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // ...

        runSlowProcess();
        // no async support, thread will be free when runSlowProcess() and
        // doGet finish

        // ...
    }

}
```

Servlets 3:

```
@WebServlet(name="myServlet",
             urlPatterns={"/mySlowProcess"},
             asyncSupported=true) // asyncSupported MUST be specified for
                                  // servlets that support asynchronous
                                  // processing
public class MyAwesomeServlet extends HttpSerlvet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {


        // an AsyncContext is created, now the response will be completed
        // not when doGet finalizes its execution, but when
        // myAsyncContext.complete() is called.
        AsyncContext myAsyncContext = request.startAsync(request, response);

        // ...

        // myAsyncContext is passed to another thread
        delegateExecutionToProcessingThread(myAsyncContext);

        // done, now this thread is free to serve another request
    }

}

// ... and somewhere in another part of the code:

public class MyProcessingObject {

    public void doSlowProcess() {

        // ...

        runSlowProcess();
        myAsyncContext.complete(); // request is now completed.

        // ...

    }

}
```

The interface `AsyncContext` also has methods to get the request object, response object and add listeners to notify them when a process has finished.

### Programmatic login and logout (security enhancements)

In servlets 3, the interface `HttpServletRequest` has been added two new methods: `login(username, password)` and `logout()`.

For more details, have a look at the [Java EE 6 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/).

Comment: It is worth a mention that Servlet 3.0 was released back in december 2009. The question and the current accepted answer answer predate those.

Comment: `@ServletFilter` → `@WebFilter` and `@WebServletContextListener` → `@WebListener` in official specs AFAICT.

Answer (score 21):

Servlet 3.0 has not yet been released, but it looks like it's very close. The most important changes in 3.0 are: Pluggability, Ease of development, Async Servlet, Security. Whether or not these are important to you is impossible for me to say.

The most significant of these is probably the support for asynchronous Servlets. Here's [an article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html) that describes this in detail. The full specification can be downloaded [here](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr315/index.html).

Comment: Holy crap, that's great. The async stuff looks awesome, thanks for the info. I have just finished coding something very similar to this.

Comment: @adi it was released in Dec. 2009 ( https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/ )

Comment: **UPDATE** [Servlet 3.1 spec](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340) released 2013-05. See [what's new](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/what_s_new_in_servlet).

Answer (score 13):

As Don mentioned, the main areas of improvements and additions are:

- Pluggability (modularizing of web.xml)
- Ease of development (annotations, generics, convention over configuration)
- Async servlet support (for comet style programming, async web proxy, async web services)
- Security enhancements (programmatic login/logout)
- Others (HttpOnly Cookie, Session tracking, EJB in WAR file)

Check out the Javaone 2008 presentation "[Java Servlet 3.0 API: What's new and exciting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/ts-5415-159162.pdf)" for details.

Answer (score 1):

[This link will give enough info on Servlet 3](http://www.javabeat.net/new-features-in-servlets-3-0/)

Servlet 3 supports annotation to eliminate `web.xml`

```
@WebServlet
@WebServletContextListener
@ServletFilter
@InitParam
```