# Java SE Version <-> Java EE Version compatibility matrix

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I noticed today's announcement of the coming end of public updates for Java SE 6 at [The Java Source](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/entry/end_of_public_updates_for?msgid=3-7555351270). I currently work on a web application that uses Java EE 5, which prompted the question in my mind if I should be pushing for updating to Java EE 6.

- [JSR 244](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=244) states that "Java EE 5 [is] built on J2SE 5.0"
- [JSR 316](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316) states that "Java EE 6 [is] built on Java SE 6"
- [JSR 342](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=342) states that "Java EE 7 [will build] on Java SE 7", but also encourages supporting JSR's to look to new Java SE 8 language features

Given that I currently build using OpenJDK 7 and deploy on Tomcat 7, I suspect that the compatibility matrix looks like this:

```
    EE5 EE6 EE7
SE5  x
SE6  x   x
SE7  x   x   x
```

Is it OK for our project to keep basing our code on Java EE 5 and utilize features from Java SE 6 or Java SE 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it OK for our project to keep basing our code on Java EE 5 and
>   utilize features from Java SE 6 or Java SE 7?

Yes, that's fine, though you might want to upgrade your Java EE version at some point as well.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at the [differences](http://alexander.holbreich.org/2011/01/javaee5-vs-javaee6/). My application is pretty small scale. I have recently introduced some AJAX code, so Servlet 3.0, introduced in EE 6, [may be of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638865/what-are-the-differences-between-servlet-2-5-and-3).