# Can a webapp run without Deployment descriptor?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I'm using Eclipse to create some basic jsp files with the help of Tomcat, and I was able to run and render a jsp file (on Mozilla Firefox), but then I read that one also should have a "deployment descriptor" file (web.xml), in order to "tell the application container how the web app should be configured".

I don't remember creating one, and I checked to see if Eclipse created a default one for me but couldn't find in anywhere in my project files...

Do I have to provide it, or is it just optional?

Comment: In servlets 2.5 you have to provide a web.xml, in servlets 3.0 it is optional and you can replace it with annotations. For more details check [this answer in another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18187372/2164109)

Comment: According to Servlet Specification Version 2.5:

**A web application is NOT required to contain a web.xml if it does NOT contain any Servlet, Filter, or Listener components. In other words an application containing only static files or JSP pages does not require a web.xml to be present.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't use deployment descriptor you have to use annotations in your classes which are supported in servlet 3.0 and higher

Answer (score 0):

No it's not optional it is required to have a deployment descriptor in your deployed project. Since the deployment descriptor tells the application container how the web app should be configured.