# Difference between Spring 4 MVC (servelt 2.5) and Spring 4 MVC (Servlet 3.0) Integrations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a lot of questions to design an final architecture of Spring 4 MVC. 
1. What are the features of Spring 4 MVC (servlet 2.5)  and Spring 4 MVC (Servlet 3.0)?
2. Which is the best choose among the either Spring MVC (servlet 2.5)  and Spring MVC (Servlet 3.0)? 
3. I went to below link provided by spring API.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html
Still I have a lot of confusions to decide like Spring 4 MVC (Servlet 3.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlet 2.5 has XML based configuration. but in Servlet 3 it is optional you can use either xml or use annotation.

Comment: brief discription is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638865/what-are-the-differences-between-servlet-2-5-and-3